# Python vs Java, For-Loop

Tags: java, python-3.x, debugging

I was trying a simple recursive problem in python and was stumped by the for-loop-esq implementation in python. The implementation uses the range(x,y,z) function.

Here is the code in python:

```
num = 25
f1 = 0
f2 = 1

for num in range(1,num,1):
    num = f1 + f2
    f1 = f2
    f2 = num

print("num is : ", num)
```

Same code in java:

```
int num = 25;
int f1 = 0;
int f2 = 1;
for(int i = 1; i < num; i++){
    num = f1 + f2;
    f1 = f2;
    f2 = num;
}
System.out.println("# at 25 is : " + num);
```

The java implementation will never spit out the right answer (75025) because `num` is overwritten in the first line of the for-loop (`num = f1 + f2`).
Where as in python, the code executes and delivers the right answer. How come? Does python implement some sort of `i` counter under the hood?
I'm using the pyCharm debugger to test this.

Comment: This is not recursion, recursion is when a function calls itself, which is not the case here, you are simply looping

Comment: despite the different behavior between `java` and `python`, why do you need to change a variable that shoud be used to control the loop? if you want to execute 25 times, don't change the variable. If you want a more "flexible" loop, use `while` instead

Comment: @ArthurAttout You're right, I was trying the for-loop implementation of the problem.

Comment: @RicardoPontual The whole question stems from a typo and curiosity. I know what the correct implementation is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the difference is that the range function in Python has arguments passed by value. So even after you give the **num** variable a new value, the function still holds on to the 25 you gave it originally, and thus iterates 25 times.

In Java the loop is checking the value of **num** after every iteration to see when to stop. Since the value of **num** changed to 1 during the first iteration, it met the criteria to stop the loop, so it only iterates one time.

I hope that makes sense!

Comment: Ah! that does make sense. Now I'm decending down a "Pass By Ref vs Pass by Value" rabbit hole. First legitimate answer. Thanks!
http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/11/does-python-pass-by-value-or-by.html

Comment: I'm glad I could help clarify!

Answer (score 1):

In the first iteration of the for loop, you set num to 1 (`num = f1 + f2`). Since `num` is used in your loop condition, the loop will stop after the first iteration. To get it working the same way as the python code you will need another variable and keep `num` at 25

```
    int num = 25;
    int f1 = 0;
    int f2 = 1;
    int res = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < num; i++) {
        res = f1 + f2;
        f1 = f2;
        f2 = res;
    }
    System.out.println("# at 25 is : " + res);
```

Comment: Lars, that wasn't the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the function in `range(1, num, 1)` only sees something like this in `range(1,25,1)` or in other word it is function with arguments passed by value.

The return value of the function range should be something like `[1,2,3 ...25]`.